# Bootstrap navbar covers top of section when linked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on my first website for learning purposes and run into this problem:

Whenever I link to a specific place on the same page it opens up as intended but the top is covered with navbar.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="50">
   <nav id="myNavbar" role="navigation" class="container-fluid navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
               <span class="sr-only"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
         </div>
         <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#section2">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a></li>
               <li><a href="#section4">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="jumbotron" id="section1">
      <h1 class="header"></h1>
      <hr class="style" />
      <un class="list-inline">
         <li>
            <a href="#">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Facebook
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> GitHub
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> LinkedIn
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </un>
   </div>
</body>
```

Is there any way to make it link below the navbar so that it wouldn't cover the top of section?

Have tried playing with body's padding-top but to no use.

(I was able to solve this by linking to separate divs and adjusting them vie CSS, but after the implementation of bootstrap scrollspy divs that cover whole section had o be targeted, thus the problem returned.)

P.S.: no JS/Query has been used.

Comment: Share your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help or give you some ideas; you're essentially just using two navbars together under a `navbar-fixed-top` class so they're then together on scroll.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar.nav-lower {
  height: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus,
.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.nav-lower > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
#section1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1E88E5;
}
#section2 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #673ab7;
}
#section3 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
#section4 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-lower .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: left;
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default.nav-lower .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default.nav-lower .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default.nav-lower .nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default.nav-lower .nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" id="myNavbar">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#section2">About</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#section4">Contact</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-lower">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-lower-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-lower-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Facebook
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> GitHub
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> LinkedIn
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </nav>
  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4</h1>

    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
</body>
```